# Why is formatting a USB as FAT32 quicker than formatting as EXT3?

Tags: filesystems, gparted, ext3, fat32

I often use gparted to format my USBs. Whenever I format a USB as FAT32, it takes just a few seconds to complete. Whenever I format a USB as EXT3, it takes a few minutes to complete. Why is there such a large difference in the speeds of formatting the USB in these different formats?

Answer (score 1):

FAT32 is an older filesystem that is incredibly simple and robust. EXT3 is a newer, journaled filesystem which is to say that it tracks changes. I'm not sure how the journaling is implemented on the disk, but I would guess that there are a few words of each block that need to be written to when the drive is formatted. That disk IO is probably what is causing the wait. The wikipedia articles for [EXT3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) and [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) seem to be pretty good if you wanted to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

With EXT3 you might be experiencing a disk check happening automatically.
I know when using SUSE and Yast-Partitioner a disk check happens automatically whenever I format anything with EXT3.  And if I am formatting something like a 12 drive raid volume it will take much much longer to fully finish formatting because of the disk check, compared to formatting just 1 drive.

`gparted` is the graphical front end to `parted`.  Try looking in to `parted` and see if a disk check such as `fsck` or `e2fsck` is happening by default.  You may be able to give `parted` a flag to tell it not to disk check after formatting, but how you might do this from the graphical `gparted` i don't know.